# Dojo call template on change of layout

Tags: dojo

I'm quite new to Dojo and trying to accomplish a table widget. I have a widget that contains the actual table element and generates it´s headers. Then I have one widget that is called to create each row and fill it with information.
The thing I'm struggling with is that I want each row to be clickable and on the click event I want to re-render the contents of the row and add some data to it.

Is there any way to have a second template file that I can call on the click event to change layout of the row?